# Daemon library for FreeBSD

Tags: daemon, freebsd

I am contemplating writing a daemon programme for FreeBSD, however, I've never done it, and by the looks of it, it's quite tricky.

Are there any libraries that I could include and then just write the things specific for my daemon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for posting this an answer rather than a comment - I don't have enough reputation to do the latter.

You might want to look at daemon(3), a function provided in FreeBSD's libc. It does things like close the standard file descriptors, set things up so SIGHUP will have no effect, and so on. The source code is here:

http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/gen/daemon.c?view=markup

There's also a man page. (Be careful, there's also a wrapper program, daemon(1)). Also note that it's not portable (though it may be available in libbsd, I'm not sure).

FreeBSD also provides libutil (again, not portable I think), which among other things provides pidfile_*() functions for handling PID files, which I suppose is useful for writing a daemon. There are other considerations, but this might help you get started. Can't say much more unless you have a specific question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it was very helpful. As to more specific things -- i want to be also able to send it messages from terminal or cron, something like transmission-daemon (which is communicated to by transmission-remote, i believe).

Comment: If you know that the daemon and client processes will always run on the same machine, the best route is to use a unix-domain socket. The idea is to have the daemon create a socket on start-up with some standard name (i.e. something like ${HOME}/.daemon/socket, or maybe something in /var/run), and have the client look for this socket. This stuff is pretty standard: here's a quick tutorial: beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html

Transmission uses IP sockets and has some RPC library, so it's a bit more complicated. syslogd might be a good place to look for examples.

Comment: (probably should have mentioned that unix-domain sockets are objects in the file system, so they're found using a file name rather than URL+port as with IP sockets. They're all manipulated using the same interface though, socket(), bind(), etc.)